# git branch is ahead of origin/master while repo is in sync

Tags: git, github

Folks,

This is something in git that just does not make sense to me, here is what happens

- I do a `git status`, I see that I am on branch master and nothing to commit and working directory is clean.
- I then do `git pull origin master` I pull a bunch of code, no issues.
- Now when I do `git status` I see a new line **Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit**

My local repo and remote repo are totally in sync, what does **your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit** mean, this is very very confusing.

Comment: Why do you think your repository is in sync with the remote?

Comment: You're not rebasing by default in your pull do you? Could you try fetching and merging separately instead of pulling?

Comment: You can use "gitk ." to see which commits has the "master" and "origin/master" labels attached.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I think you are pointing in the right direction, but I do not understand why I need to re-base, what is wrong in the sequence I am following.

Comment: your assumption that your local repository and remote repository is totally in sync, is incorrect.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thanks, **gitk .** looks very good, I am going through it now

Comment: so when I did a pull, I got a commit(eng-3) from my co-worker. I see the code in my local repo now. when I do a **gitk .** it says that eng-3 is on branch master and everything before that is on branch /remotes/origin/master , not sure why. I would imagine since I got eng-3 from remote it should be in the remote branch.

Comment: @user1781472: I'm not saying you need to rebase. A `pull` is equivalent to a `fetch` followed by a `merge`, unless you've configured it to be equivalent to a `fetch` followed by a `rebase`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have experienced exactly what you see. 
I can't find the proper explanation on git-scm.com but I believe it to be something like this:

1. I clone a repo from origin, lets say origin has master and I have master now in my local repo
2. now origin and your repo have a reference to the last commit. This reference is the master branch AND the reference is the same in your local repo and on origin
3. Let's say someone (other then you) pushes new commits to origin master
4. you do `git pull origin master`
5. now you do `git status` and you will see that your branch is ahead to origin/master even tough you have no new commits in your local repo and nothing to push!! (in this example, you did not commit anything new locally since step 1 (the cloning))

==> I fix this by doing a `git pull origin` when I'm on master.

A `git pull origin master` will pull all new commits from a branch on origin to your local branch.

A `git pull origin` will also re-set your reference to master equal to the commit where master is referenced on origin!! (When this didn't happen, the git-bash will just think that you are alot of commits ahead! because in the commit-tree there are alot of commits made after the commit where your master-reference is!)

Does this make any sence to you? It does to me :)

Also please feel free to support my toughts a bit with hard evidence/documentation :)

Comment: please also read the comments below the answer of blunderboy. There user1781472 says what solved his issue + some comments on why it did solve his issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have added a commit on your local machine, which has not yet been sent to the remote server.

If you are confident your modifications should be shared with the remote repository, sending the commit to the remote is done with the `git push` command :

```
git push orgin master:master
```

Comment: no, thats the whole point, I dont have anything on my local machine that is not committed.

Comment: What is the  difference between **git push origin master** and **git push origin master:origin/master**

Comment: First off : my mistake, the comand should read `git push origin master:master` - corrected in the post.

Comment: if `master` is set to track `origin/master`, there is no difference. It just allows you to explicitly state which remote branch you are targeting - you could write `git push origin master:testing` or whatever.

Comment: @user1781472, that is the point: Locally you have a commit newer than the last on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

You are not in 100% in sync with the remote repository as you're thinking.  You have everything from the remote repository, yes.  But your local master is ahead of origin/master by one commit.

Run this, and show us the results:

```
git log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%h %d %s'
```

I expect to see something like:

```
* (master) Commit D
* (origin/master) Commit C
* Commit B
* Commit A
```

If I'm reading your post correctly, you are one commit ahead because you have D whereas the remote branch is at C.  You will have to `git push` to push up commit D to the remote repository.  Then you will be 100% in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is your assumption that your local branch and remote branch is in sync. If it is saying that your local branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit then surely it is. We all trust GIT.

Use this to test.

```
git checkout master // You move to master branch
cat .git/HEAD //shows the commit on which HEAD is pointing to

git checkout origin/master //you switch to origin master branch
cat .git/HEAD
```

If you see that HEAD in your local master and remote master branch point to same commit then both are in sync.

If your local branch is ahead of 1 commit, just push it (if you want) to your remote branch as

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so I just checked on both local(git log) and remote before reading this and they both have the same recent commit. Then I did a **git fetch** and now that message is gone, which said my branch is ahead by 1 commit. Looks like whatever I got by git pull git thought that is my commit which is not pushed and git fetch resolved that, no idea whats going on here

Comment: 1. Have you pushed your commit to origin. If you have not pushed it, then your commit can not elapse.
2. Have you reset HEAD with hard option ? Because this also removes commit from your branch.

Comment: @user1781472: On the git-scm website I found the following: Update the remote-tracking branches:

$ git fetch origin
The above command copies all branches from the remote refs/heads/ namespace and stores them to the local refs/remotes/origin/ namespace, unless the branch.<name>.fetch option is used to specify a non-default refspec.

Comment: [here in the example section](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch): the `git fetch origin` solved it for you. So will the `git pull origin`, because this is actually a `git fetch origin` and a `git merge origin` grouped